# Selenium + C# - How to set chrome driver path whilst having chrome.options

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, driver

How can I set chrome driver path whilst having chrome.options. At the moment I am creating options to remove mic/camera permissions in chrome but I am having to feed the options path into the driver.

Here is my code at the moment for an idea. The chrome driver is starting up and working fine with the chrome.options setting being applied but I'd like to know  a way to feed the variables chromeDriverPath and options when creating the new driver

I am new with selenium so please no judgement :)

```
        IWebDriver driver;
    string chromeDriverPath;        

    void SetChromeDriverPath()
    {
        OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
        string osName = os.Platform.ToString().ToLower();
        if (osName == "win32nt")
            chromeDriverPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() + "\\tools\\selenium\\chrome\\windows\\";
        if (osName == "unix")
            chromeDriverPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() + "\\tools\\selenium\\chrome\\linux\\";
        if (osName == "macosx")
            chromeDriverPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() + "\\tools\\selenium\\chrome\\mac\\";
    }
            
    public IWebDriver GetChromeDriver()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
        options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
        SetChromeDriverPath();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        return driver;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriver.htm

you can see that the chromedriver path is expected as an argument to chromedriver so you can use:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverPath ,options);
```